# Find prefix, suffix and coincidents in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a script in Javascript that performs markup functions, similar to the browser's ctr + f function. It shouldn't be difficult, but I have to check four criteria that I check on a switch, the criteria are "Matches", "Starts with" , "Ends with" and "Any position". I'm using the window.find() method, but I seem to be having trouble with it.
In other words, I need to be able to highlight "Lor" for the "Starts with" criteria and "em" for the "Ends with" criteria and of course "Lorem" for the "Coincident" criteria.

Can someone help me?

```js
function HighLightText() {

    var contentElement = document.getElementById("content");
    let word = document.getElementById("word").value;
    let className = "search-mark";
    let criterial = "Any position"; //Can be "Ends with" | "Starts with" | "Coincident".
    let scrollDetail = false;
    
    var searchResults = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    

    if (window.find && window.getSelection) {
        document.designMode = "on";

        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.collapse(document.body, 0);
        var listOfWord = [];
        switch (criterial) {
            case "Coincident":     
                  listOfWord.push(" " + word + ""); 
                listOfWord.push(word + " "); 
               // ...more cases where the word is found
                break;
            case "Any position":
                listOfWord.push(word);
                break;
            case "Ends with":
                listOfWord.push(word + ".");
                listOfWord.push(word + ",");
                listOfWord.push(word + "!");
                listOfWord.push(word + "?");
                // ...more cases where the word is found
                break;
            case "Starts with":
                listOfWord.push(" " + word);
                // ...more cases where the word is found
                break;

        }

        listOfWord.forEach(singleWord => {
            while (window.find(singleWord)) {  
                scroll(0, scrollDetail)
                document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, '<b><mark>' + window.getSelection().toString() + '</mark></b>');
            }
        });
        
        sel.collapseToEnd();
        document.designMode = "off";
    } else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(contentElement);
        while (textRange.findText(text)) {
            
            textRange.execCommand("BackColor", false, "yellow");
            textRange.collapse(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MadDev82/97sdn0mr/4/

Thanks!

Comment: [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find) ... I've last seen it somewhat 15 years ago, I thought it was removed from the DOM. I'd suggest you to use [Node API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) instead, that would make it possible to use RegExps for searching.

Comment: offtopic, but... Why the old `<mark>` selections do not reset on a new *search*? PS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find **Do not use** is so bolded that it almost hurts.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an idea from the **[Hilite NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rbuljan/hilite)**  (*Disclaimer:Author*) which `highlight()` method has a check for the desired match criteria:

```js
//...

const val_escaped = regEscape(this._value);

const val_criteria = {
  any: val_escaped,
  start: `(?<=^| )${val_escaped}`,
  end: `${val_escaped}(?=$| )`,
  full: `(?<=^| )${val_escaped}(?=$| )`,
}[this._criteria];

this._reg = new RegExp(val_criteria, this.sensitive ? "g" : "ig");

//...
```

where for a (reg-escaped!) value:

1. if the criteria is `"any"` the value is used as is
2. if the criteria is `"start"` the lookbehind regex `(?<=^| )` is prepended to the value
3. if the criteria is `"end"` the lookahead regex `(?=$| )` is appended to the value
4. if the criteria is `"full"` (as for *full match*) both the lookbehind and lookahead are added to the string

which is than passed to the `new RegExp` constructor.

***Demo:***

```html
<input value="" type="search" id="search" placeholder="Find" autocomplete="off" />
<select id="criteria">
  <option disabled>Select match criteria: </option>
  <option value="any" selected>Any</option>
  <option value="start">Starts with</option>
  <option value="end">Ends with</option>
  <option value="full">Full match</option>
</select>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="sensitive"> Case sensitive</label>

<div id="area">Highlight height right<br>ribbon Rough hi high, HI!</div>

<script type="module">
  import { Hilite } from "https://unpkg.com/@rbuljan/hilite@1.2.0";
  
  const HL = new Hilite("#area");
  const EL_search = document.querySelector("#search");
  const EL_criteria = document.querySelector("#criteria");
  const EL_sensitive = document.querySelector("#sensitive");

  // Do on search "input"
  EL_search.addEventListener("input", () => HL.value = EL_search.value);
  // Change match criteria
  EL_criteria.addEventListener("input", () => HL.criteria = EL_criteria.value);
  // Change case
  EL_sensitive.addEventListener("input", () => HL.sensitive = EL_sensitive.checked);
</script>
```

Comment: Nice! I was writing an answer too, but got stuck to lookahead/behind RegExps. My code has the same issue as yours, it includes full mathces in Starts with/Ends with results. I'm not sure if this would be accepted by OP, but I'm still trying to exclude full matches from those results.

Comment: @Teemu thx! There's no issue. Think about it. A full match means a full match. A "Starts with" `hi!` **should** -highlight the word `HI!` even if it both starts and ends-with.

Comment: Well, maybe it's a bit ambiguous, we'll see what OP thinks about it when they return at their question.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks for pointing that out. I re-read the question and I think I understand now the Op's thoughts about what "coincident" should be an I completely disagree with his implementation - if that's not a mistake.  But the answer to a question: *Does "hello" starts with the word "hello"?* - ***yes.*** And one should accept that as a valid reality. Otherwise, to search for exact matches - there's the option to do so.

Comment: My sense says, that a word with a space in front of it and ending to a punctuation mark is a full word, it's not a _prefix_ nor a _suffix_. But like I said, the rules are a bit ambiguous, and even language-dependent. In my native language (finnish) there are three different dashes (hyphen, em-dash and en-dash) which all have their official use-cases, though lazy writers mostly use hyphen only. It looks like what ever rules we include into our answers, the enduser have to fit the RegExps to the used language.

Comment: @Teemu I understand. The above is not focused on **words** specifically, but rather on ***characters value***. Just like hitting CRTL+F in browser any searching for `hi!` (with the exclamation character). I find it quite superior (and frankly, easier!). I removed any *"word/s"* words from my answer to reduce ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

As [`window.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find) is deprecated, I'd manipulate the DOM [textNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) directly. Something like this:

```js
function searchTextNodes(target, ref) {
  // target: Element to search from <HTMLElement>
  // ref:    Keyword or RegExp to search for <String|RegExp>
  let inNode = 0;
  const key = (ref instanceof RegExp) ? ref : new RegExp(ref),
    matches = [],
    references = [],
    // Store the matching nodes and the matched strings
    textNodes = Array.from(target.childNodes).filter(node => {
      key.lastIndex = 0;
      if (node.nodeType === 3 && key.test(node.data)) {
        matches.push(node.data.match(key));
        return true;
      }
    });
  // Split the nodes of target to match the matches
  for (const textNode of textNodes) {
    let node = textNode;
    for (const text of matches[inNode]) {
      const start = node.data.search(key);
      node.splitText(start + text.length);
      const currentRef = node.splitText(start);
      references.push(currentRef);
      node = currentRef.nextSibling;
    }
    inNode += 1;
  }
  return references;
}

const modes = {
  prefix: (key, flags) => new RegExp(`(?<=\\b)(${key})(?=\\w)`, flags),
  suffix: (key, flags) => new RegExp(`(?<=\\w)(${key})(?=\\b)`, flags),
  word: (key, flags) => new RegExp(`\\b(${key})\\b`, flags),
  any: (key, flags) => new RegExp(`(${key})`, flags)
}

function reset(content) {
  const marks = content.querySelectorAll('mark');
  marks.forEach(mark => {
    const textNode = document.createTextNode(mark.textContent),
      parent = mark.parentNode;
    parent.replaceChild(textNode, mark);
    parent.normalize();
  });
}

function search() {
  const content = document.querySelector('.content');
  reset(content);
  const regexSpecials = /([\^\$.:=*?+()[\]{}|\\])/g,    
    elements = content.querySelectorAll('*'),
    searchMode = document.querySelector('input[name="mode"]:checked').value,
    keyword = document.querySelector('[name="keywords"]').value.replace(regexSpecials, '\\$1'),
    flags = (document.querySelector('[name="case"]').checked) ? 'gi' : 'g',
    regex = modes[searchMode](keyword, flags);
  
  elements.forEach(element => {
    if (element.nodeType > 3 || element.tagName === 'SCRIPT') {return;} // Next, exclude scripts, comments etc.
    const nodes = searchTextNodes(element, regex);
    nodes.forEach(node => {
      const mark = document.createElement('mark');
      mark.textContent = node.textContent;
      element.replaceChild(mark, node);
    });
  });
}

const searchBut = document.querySelector('button');
searchBut.addEventListener('click', search);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="keywords" value="text">
<button>Search</button>
<br>
<label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="prefix"> Prefix</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="suffix"> Suffix</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="word" checked> Word</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="any"> Any</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="case" checked> Ignore case</label>

<hr>
<div class="content">
  <h1>Text search</h1>

  <p>A test text for searching TextNodes from a text.</p>
  <p>This paragraphtext contains more than one text-word, the textsearching engine should find all the text from this text.</p>
  <p>This word is unique within the testtext to search for.</p>
</div>
```

The idea of the code is to extract the keyword(s) into their own textNodes within the specified element (`.content` in this case), and then wrap the new nodes with `<mark>`. The advantage is, that you can select an element to search from, it doesn't have to be the entire document.

`searchTextNodes` finds the keywords and extracts them into textNodes in a single element. The function is called from the iteration of all the elements within the specified element. The "UI" handling is integrated in `search` function, but if needed, it's easy to pull out and parametrize the function instead.

`searchTextNodes` is a generic textNode finder, which you can use outside of this snippet where needed.

Comment: be aware that - say you have a string like i.e: *"Say hello! dear"* - and if you search for `"lo!"` - you will get no results - just because you used `\b`. Word boundaries are simply **not the right tool**. Otherwise - the implementation seems pretty similar. :) cool

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Indeed, also my solution fails with non-english characters, which your snippet seems to be able to handle. I took a look at your npm code, and made the same observation, the base is quite similar. I just made a collection of functions like for starters for OP to put up their real code.