# How to replace matching words within a page replacing the body.innerHTML only once?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, replace

The following function in `JavaScript` adds to each matching word a `<mark>` tag in the document's body.

```
var words = ["apple", "banana", "carrot", "pear"];  

for (var i=0; i < words.length; i++) {
  var replace = new RegExp(words[i],"g");
  var page = document.body.innerHTML;
  var newPage = page.replace(replace, `<mark>${words[i]}</mark>`);
  document.body.innerHTML = newPage;
}
```

This way, it highlights a word within the `<body>` if it's an element within the array `words`.

The issue I have is that the `document.body.innerHTML` is replaced at every iteration. Do you know how I can replace the matching words in the page limiting the numbers of `document.body.innerHTML = newPage` to 1?

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: Apply one of the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70715023/find-prefix-suffix-and-coincidents-in-javascript) ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get innerHTML before loop and set innerHTML after loo. you can use replaceAll to change all matching word

```js
var words = ["apple", "banana", "carrot", "pear"];
var page = document.body.innerHTML;

words.forEach((word)  => {
  page = page.replaceAll(word, `<mark>${word}</mark>`);
});

document.body.innerHTML = page;
```

```html
<div> apple abc banana cd apple </div>
```

Comment: This will eat all the event listeners if they're attached with JS. Setting innerHTML is always a bad idea,

Comment: @Teemu Can you propose an alternative?

Comment: @d_z90 I've linked to working solutions in my comment to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Read the string before the loop, modify it in the loop, and change the document body after the loop.

```js
const words = ["apple", "banana", "carrot", "pear"];  
let page = document.body.innerHTML;

for (const word of words) {
  page = page.replaceAll(word, `<mark>${word}</mark>`);
}
document.body.innerHTML = page;
```

```html
"apple", "banana", "carrot", "pear"
```

Or you can use `reduce`:

```js
const words = ["apple", "banana", "carrot", "pear"];  
document.body.innerHTML = words.reduce((page, word) => page.replaceAll(word, `<mark>${word}</mark>`), document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
"apple", "banana", "carrot", "pear"
```