# How can I do text interpolation in HTML and JS like I do in Angular? (If possible)

Tags: javascript, html, string-interpolation

I want to do a text interpolation in HTML and JS like i usually do in angular, I know that it doesn't work if I do the exact same way:

```js
var myPhrase = 'This is my phrase>!';
```

```html
<body>
  <p> {{myPhrase}} </p>
</body>
```

Since the angular way is "easier", I'm trying to avoid the text insertion by the `myTag.innerHTML = 'something here'`
So my question is: If possible how can I do it?

Comment: there is nothing like that in javascript, you have to find `<p>` element and change its' content

Comment: Use a proper data structure (object) to store the data instead of variables, then create textnodes from the placeholders, and replace the nodes with the correct content.

Comment: That's what I thought, just wanted to make sure if there was a way to do it or not, thank you for the answer @FlashThunder.

Comment: I think I'm just going to put the text via innerHTML or something, but thanks for the sugestion @Teemu

Comment: Don't do that. you'll only make a mess of your page. Take a look at [this my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70722437/1169519). Though it's not a direct answer to your question, It contains a method for searching the placeholders, and some guidance for how to replace the content fluently. There was also an answer, which shows how `innerHTML` can make a mess of your page, but that answer is currently deleted.

Comment: The code I'm working with now is a little bit messy but I'll try the way you sugested then. thank you @Teemu

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't believe you can do this in vanilla JS. Perhaps you could do something like this:

```js
let greeting = 'Hello World!';
let message = 'How is the weather today?';

let str2 =
    `<h1>${greeting}</h1>
    <p>${message}</p>`;

console.log(str2);
```

But this does not have the same ease of use. You will probably have to use
`myTag.innerHTML = 'something here'`
as you said.

Comment: There's a lot of secrets in JS and DOM you haven't learnt yet, of course [it is possible](https://jsfiddle.net/bm8t2adk/1/) ; ).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about that. However, that is a lot more bulky than just using innerHTML? Using a framework is supposed to reduce the amount of effort in this case.

Comment: A framework is much more bulky itself, but yes, that's the puprose. [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) isn't an ideal tool for manipulating an existing document, it re-creates all the elements, and if you've event listeners attached to the old elements or references to those, they all stop working, it's really easy to break your code with innerHTML. Notice also all the security warnings in the linked MDN article. `searchTextNodes` in my example is like a micro framework, it can be used anywhere you need to manipulate existing elements.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done but it's cumbersome and not pretty. You simpley embed `script` tags in the html and `document.write` output as needed.

This is one of the few examples where `document.write` can be used successively as each use is occurring while the page is being interpretted.

```html
<body>
  <p> <script>document.write("hello")</script> world, <script>let phrase="how are you today?"; document.write(phrase);</script></p>
</body>
```

in the context of filling in stored data, each variable can be defined in an earlier script (so will be available to the future insering tags. Like this:

```html
<script>
let myName = "David";
let myAge = "99";
let myBirthday = "tomorrow";
</script>

<h2>Hello, my name is <script>document.write(myName);</script></h2>

<p>It's my birthday <script>document.write(myBirthday);</script></p>

<p><script>document.write(`I will be ${myAge} years old`);</script></p>
```