# Highlight exact keywords with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, select, text, highlight

I have a list of keywords and I need to highlight it on target page.

I have such code:

```
let list = ["AMD", "Intel", "ATI", "core", "code", "error"] 

function highlight_words(word) {
    const page = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = page.replace(new RegExp(word, "gi"), (match) => `<mark>${match}</mark>`);
}

for (const index in list) {
  highlight_words(list[index]);
}
```

But now it highlights **ANY** text (even part of it) that contains elements from **list**.

For example: I have word 'cores', and part of it - "core" will be highlighted.
But it is not correct, because I am looking for "single core" on page ;)

In some cases it even broke the page :(

How I can modify my code to solve my issue?

Comment: Try adding `\b` before and after each word. `\b` is a word boundary token. See more at https://regex101.com/

Comment: You're destroying the page by re-setting `innerHTML` of `body` (if a keyword matches a tag or attribute name, also those will be changed). Take a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70722437/1169519), it shows you how to modify TextNodes and use RegExp to find the keywords. In your case a suitable RegExp would be a "whitelist" like `/AMD|Intel|ATI|core|code|error/g`.

Comment: Try to use CodeMirror or other similar products. For example, on your post, the code part is high lighted and it will work in your own webpage. CodeMirror also enables us to add our own highlight words, you can found information on the internet.