# JQuery: how to wrap given section of text in a span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexof

I have a series of title elements with text in them and a text input. When I put a string into the text input I want to highlight (wrapp in `<span>` with a class) the responding character(s) within the title elements.

For example, if the text input contains the word "world" then I want that same word to be wrapped in high light span, eg

```
<div class="title">Hello <span class="highlight">World</span>! This is a title</div>
```

I have achieved this somewhatr with `.replace()` eg:

```
// value is .val recieved from input
function highlight(value) {
    $('.title').each(function() {
        var original = $(this).text();
        var newText = original.replace(value, "<span class='highlight'>" + value + "</span>");
        $(this).html(newText);
    });
};
```

However, this has a couple of limitations:

1. It doesn't work with capitalisation (if user enters `world` the string `World` won't be highlighted).
2. It only works on the first instance of the word (if there are multiple instances of the word `world` in the string it will only highlight the first.

I tried to approach this a different way by inserting the `<span>`s by getting the start and end positions of each inputted string, but this just created a mess:

```
function highlight(value, el) {
    $(el).each(function() {
        var original = $(this).text();
        var startPosition = original.indexOf(value);
        
        if (startPosition !== 0 || startPosition !== -1) {
            var endPosition = (startPosition + value.length);
                            
           var newString = original.slice(0, startPosition)
            + '<span class="highlight">'
            + original.slice(startPosition, endPosition)
            + '</span>'
            + original.slice(startPosition);
            
            $(this).html(newString);
        }
    });
};
```

Would anyone know if this is possible to do? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

(PS: I'd rather not use plugins if possible)

Comment: A document consist of [nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node), one type of node is Text. Setting HTML of an existing document most often leads to more or less broken page, because it replaces existing elements with new elements. Create text nodes from the found words and wrap the nodes with an element instead. An example would be [like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70722437/1169519), you can search for more advanced code snippets on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regexp

There is not much gained by only grabbing titles containing the word, since that will loop too

```js
function highlight(value) {
  $('.title').each(function() {
    let textContent = $(this).text(); 
    const wordArr = [...new Set(textContent.match(new RegExp(value, 'ig')))];
    if (wordArr.length > 0) { 
      wordArr.forEach(word => textContent = textContent.split(word).join(`<span class="highlight">${word}</span>`));
      $(this).html(textContent);
    }
  });
};
highlight("wor");
```

```css
.highlight  {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="title">Hello world</h1>
<h1 class="title">Hello World</h1>
<h1 class="title">Hello World Hello world</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

with the accepted answer, if the string contains more than one matching substring, it would not be highlighted

```js
function highlight(value) {
    const pattern = '\\b' + value + '\\b';
    $('.title').each(function () {
        var original = $(this).text();
        const text = original.match(new RegExp(pattern, 'gi'));
        if (text && text.length) { // null if not found
            text.forEach(item => {
                original = original.replace(item, "<span class='highlight'>" + item + "</span>");
                $(this).html(original);
            })
        }
    });
};
highlight("world");
```

```css
span {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="title">World Hello world WorLD</h1>
<h1 class="title">Hello World</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good. But is there a way to get it working without the word boundries? So it highlights parts of works as well?

Comment: Did not get what are you asking.

Comment: So if I type in "wor" I would get `<h1 class="title"><span class='highlight'>Wor</span>ld Hello <span class='highlight'>wor<span>ld <span class='highlight'>Wor</span>LD</h1>`

Comment: I updated my answer to handle more than one

Comment: Please never use map to do the work of a forEach